# How to repeat a vector of strings N times in a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I am working with a list of dataframes and want to create a new column with the names of the variables. There are three variables and the length of the dataframe is 684, therefore I need the variable names to repeat 228 times. However, I can't get this to work.

Here is the snippet I am currently using:

```
empleo = lapply(lista.empleo, function(x){x = x %>%
        read_excel(skip=4) %>% 
        head(23) %>% 
        drop_na() %>%
        clean_names() %>% 
        pivot_longer(!1, 
                     names_to = 'fecha',
                     values_to = 'valor') %>% 
        mutate(variable = rep(c('trabajadores',
                                'masa',
                                'salario'), 
                              times = 228))})
```

So far, I have tried to use mutate, but I get the following mistake:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `variable = rep(c("trabajadores", "masa",
  "salario"), times = 228)`.
x `variable` must be size 0 or 1, not 684.
```

I will add the structure of a sample df in the comments since it is too big.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The `rep` may need `length.out = n()` as some data in the list may not have the ssame number of rows i.e. `mutate(variable = rep(c('trabajadores',
                                'masa',
                                'salario'), 
                              228,  length.out = n()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rep` may fail as some datasets may have different number of rows in the `list`.  Use `length.out` to make sure it returns `n()` elements (number of rows)

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
empleo <- lapply(lista.empleo, function(x){x = x %>%
        read_excel(skip=4) %>% 
        head(23) %>% 
        drop_na() %>%
        clean_names() %>% 
        pivot_longer(!1, 
                     names_to = 'fecha',
                     values_to = 'valor') %>% 
        mutate(variable = rep(c('trabajadores',
                                'masa',
                                'salario'), 
                               228, length.out = n()))})
```